# How to call a function residing in a parent screen within an if statement in a tabNavigator (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So my problem is this:  Parent Component is a screen in a tab navigator which has another tab navigator nested in it. I am able to pass props down to the child tabs via screenProps. However I am unable to call a function in the parent screen from any of the screens in the child tab navigator. What am i doing wrong?

```
ParentScreen.js //One of the screens of a parent tab navigator


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ChildTabs } from '../navigatation/router.js';

export default class ParentScreen extends Component {
    state = { name: '' }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.parentFxn();
    }

    parentFxn() {
        this.setState({ name: 'Staker' });
    }

    render() {
        screenProps = { parentFxn: this.parentFxn.bind(this) };
        return(
            <ChildTabs  // this is a tab Navigator
                screenProps={screenProps}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Now one of the child screens:

```
ChildScreen.js
//childScreen is one of the screens in the tab navigator

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import { ChildTabs } from '../navigatation/router.js';

export default class ChildScreen extends Component {

    childFxn() {
        axios.get(someRemoteUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                return this.props.screenProps.parentFxn; //this never gets called
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Button
                onPress={this.childFxn.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nicely asked question. Was searching for this for 2 hours and finally found this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function is not getting called because you are not calling it. It should be called like this

```
  if (response.status == 200) {
     return this.props.screenProps.parentFxn(); //this always gets called
  }
```

Comment: Wow. thanks. I totally forgot to add that. Thanks alot.